# Sequelize creating 2 entries instead of 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have 2 models, `patient` & `personalInformation`.

There is an association such that `personalInformation.belongsTo(patient)`. In my case, the `patient` primary key or uuid exists as a column in the `personalInformation` table.

When my API receives a single `POST` request, I intend to make my controller create a `patient` entry and `personalInformation` entry together.

This is my controller code:

```
// patient.controller.js

const db = require('../../db/databaseConfig');
const Patient = db.patients;
const PersonalInformation = db.personalInformation;
PersonalInformation.Patient = PersonalInformation.belongsTo(Patient);

exports.create = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let payload = await req.body;
        await console.log('Recevied request: CREATE /api/patients & payload: ', payload);
        let newPatientEntry = Patient.create();
        let newPInfo = await PersonalInformation.create({
            ...payload,
            patient: newPatientEntry
        }, {
            include: [{
                association: PersonalInformation.Patient,
            }]
        });
        res.send(newPInfo);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error inside create method Patient controller');
        throw new Error(e);
    }
 };
```

Instead of 1x patient entry and 1x personalInformation entry, the result is 2x patient entries 1x personalInformation. The personalInformation entry has a patient's uuid in the table (the latter of the 2 patients created). I don't know why there are two patient entries.

Here is the relevant nodejs log:

```
2018-12-05T01:17:57.644499+00:00 app[web.1]: Executing (default): INSERT INTO "patients" ("uuid","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ('89290b66-999d-4f10-96b3-4105a26a9450','2018-12-05 01:17:57.583 +00:00','2018-12-05 01:17:57.583 +00:00') RETURNING *;
2018-12-05T01:17:57.645703+00:00 app[web.1]: Executing (default): INSERT INTO "patients" ("uuid","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ('9ed075da-757a-457b-b939-ed7e4c7b523a','2018-12-05 01:17:57.612 +00:00','2018-12-05 01:17:57.612 +00:00') RETURNING *;
2018-12-05T01:17:57.659918+00:00 app[web.1]: Executing (default): INSERT INTO "personalInformations" ("id","nameTitle","nameFirst","nameMiddle","nameLast","nameSuffix","nameAlias","dateOfBirth","sex","gender","occupation","deceased","createdAt","updatedAt","patientUuid") VALUES (DEFAULT,'Mr','Robert','Swan','Mueller','II','Bob','1950-12-15 00:00:00.000 +00:00','Male','Man','Special Counsel','False','2018-12-05 01:17:57.594 +00:00','2018-12-05 01:17:57.594 +00:00','9ed075da-757a-457b-b939-ed7e4c7b523a') RETURNING *;
```

The models are structured as follows:

```
// patient.model.js

const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Patient = sequelize.define('patient', {
        uuid: {
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.UUID,
            defaultValue: () => uuid(),
        }
    });
    return Patient;
};
```

and

```
// personalInformation.model.js

module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const PersonalInformation = sequelize.define('personalInformation', {
        nameFirst: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            notEmpty: true,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        nameLast: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            notEmpty: true,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        ... etc
        ... etc
    });
    return PersonalInformation;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will make 2 entries because you are creating it twice :

```
let newPatientEntry = Patient.create(); // <----- HERE
let newPInfo = await PersonalInformation.create({
    ...payload,
    patient: newPatientEntry // <----- HERE
}, {
    include: [{
        association: PersonalInformation.Patient,
    }]
});
```

**You can try this :**

```
// let newPatientEntry = Patient.create(); // <----- REMOVE THIS
let newPInfo = await PersonalInformation.create({
    ...payload,
    patient: {} //<---- MAKE THIS BLANK
}, {
    include: [{
        association: PersonalInformation.Patient,
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was saving an instance of the `Patient` model in `newPatientEntry`, and using that to associate it with the `PersonalInformation` instance. Your solution solved my problem.

Comment: @Scott , Glad to know , Happy Coding BTW :) .